# Can i use break or exit in Case Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN vGlTransType = 'R' THEN tkt_seq_num
      WHEN vGlTransType in ('A','E','X') then 
      break 
   END
```

Comment: Why do you want to break? What should happen?!

Comment: when first case is not satisfied , i do not want any value , i just want to exit the loop and according to me by default it is taking null when first condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Why not just add filter `WHERE vGlTransType not in ('A','E','X')` ?

Comment: i just want to have condition only for gl_trans_type 'R' and when other gl_trans_types are coming it is taking null value but i don't want any values to be assigned for other gl_trans_types

Comment: So add the `WHERE` clause!

Comment: "*i just want to exit the loop*"   there is no loop in your question

Comment: You can't use `CASE` as a flow control element.

Answer (score 0):

there is no loop in CASE
use

ELSE null

before END to return a null value when other conditions are not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Like alex mentioned, you want `ELSE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN vGlTransType = 'R' THEN tkt_seq_num
            ELSE NULL
       END
```

`ELSE NULL` is default btw, that means you could just skip it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN vGlTransType = 'R' THEN tkt_seq_num
       END
```

You got a lot of negative responses because you use the wrong vocabulary. Let me quote a [article I wrote on CASE](http://modern-sql.com/feature/case):

> SQL is a declarative language: it does not provide control over
>   program flow like if does for imperative programs. Nevertheless, SQL
>   has something similar: the case expression. Being an expression—rather
>   than a control structure—means that case varies the result of formulas
>   (expressions) based on conditions. Its use is similar to the ternary
>   operator ?: in other programming languages.

Your question suggest that you think SQL's `CASE` is similar to C's `SWITCH` (plus `CASE`). But it isn't.